# javascript..when i do POST method ..it shows an space appending

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, ionic-framework

[coding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y498M.png)

output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/915Iy.png)

it showing a extra space when i do post method using REST API method

Comment: a picture of output, and no code .... line 37 is usually the culprit

Comment: change the content type to **application/json**

Comment: when i change type...server side shows an empty data @ArpitSancheti

Comment: Use body parser at server

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing your data correctly. You need to POST the object as JSON.stringify(yourobject) and then have nodejs run jsonencoder to parse the data correctly, otherwise your request body will always be null. Below is an example.

```
var jsonencodedParser = bodyParser.json({ extended: false });

app.post('/test', jsonencodedParser, function (req, res) {
console.log('this is req.body');
console.log(req.body);
res.status(205)
res.send();
})//end function
```